# Points on meta?

Tags: discussion, votes

I've just noticed that people aren't getting points for upvotes on questions and answers on this meta site. What gives? I haven't been involved in too many stack exchange sites other than SO, let alone any beta sites, but this is definitely different than the way meta works for SO.

Okay, so now I noticed people's points are those from the main site. Super noob question, but couldn't find a duplicate so thought I'd ask. Why are there no meta points and the points from the main site integrated with this one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [FAQ](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation):

> Reputation here is entirely derived from the main website; your reputation is the same here as it is there, synchronized hourly. Votes here do not affect your reputation in any way. However, you can earn unique badges here on the meta site.

I think it is the same on all the SE2 sites...

Comment: Yes, it's the same for all SE2 sites.  Actually, I think that Meta.SO is the only one with separate rep, but maybe I'm confused.

Comment: Sorry, but what's the 2 in SE2 mean?

Comment: @Shredder He means SE 2.0, which is what all of the sites on the current network are. The sites used to be formed differently, back when Stack Exchange first became a thing beyond Stack Overflow, SuperUser, and Server Fault...but for all intents and purposes, SE 2.0 is what you currently know and use. :)

Comment: And yes, the FAQ is correct...apart from Stack Overflow, you don't earn reputation for meta activity because it's meant for open discussion about site governance, promotion, and bugs. Voting indicates something different here, too; downvotes typically mean someone disagrees with you, not necessarily that your question or answer is of poor quality.

Comment: Okay, thanks Laura! And thanks Jack.